# Attempting to change the value in a 2 dimensional array in ruby changes every value, and I don't know a workaround

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm attempting to make something that requires a two dimensional array in order to choose what to display on screen, but I've noticed some weirdness and I'm not sure how to get around it. Creating a 2d array via `Array.new` causes any attempt to set a value in 1 nested array to set it in all nested arrays.

```
a = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, 0)) #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
a[1][1] = 1                       #=> 1
a                                 #=> [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

However, making the same array by specifying every value doesnt have this same behaviour (and is how I was expecting it to work)

```
b = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]     #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
b[1][1] = 1                       #=> 1
b                                 #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I'm not exactly sure why this happens, and I can't seem to find a better way to make this array as specifying each individual value would take forever. Why is this happening, and how can I avoid it in future?

Comment: If you want separate objects, use the block form: `Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, 0) }`.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array with three references to the same object. Thus when you change one, you change them all, because they're all the same.

We can see this with `#object_id`.

```
Array.new(3, Array.new(3, 0)).map(&:object_id)
# => [70368430794940, 70368430794940, 70368430794940]
```

Using the block form of `Array#new` will resolve this.

```
Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, 0) }.map(&:object_id)
# => [70368431982020, 70368431982000, 70368431981980]
```